# Getting the output of a shell command in awk with command containing text from a field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to parse a file for some dates in a specific format and get the 'seconds since the Epoch' to calculate absolute differences between the date and the current date. I need to do this on each line using the 4th field, so I tried doing something like this:

```
"date --date=$4 +%s" | getline DUE
close("date --date=$4 +%s")
"date +%s" | getline CURR
close("date +%s")
```

Of course this doesn't quite work because `awk` interprets the $4 as a literal "$4". So I can't use variables inside that statement.

I also tried creating 2 variables with the front of the command string and the ending with a third variable being those concatenated with $4 in the middle. That didn't work as well.

I have a feeling you should be able to do such a thing. I know date parses the date just fine. The format is something like `Thu Aug 11 11:40:00 UTC 2023`

Is there any way to do this in `awk`? I've gone through a lot of documentation without ever seeing an example of fields being processed in a shell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string concatenation.

You also need quotes around the `--date` argument, since it contains whitespce.'

```
command = "date --date=\"" $4 "\" +%s"
command | getline DUE
close(command)
command2 = "date +%s"
command2 | getline CURR
close(command2)
```

Answer (score 0):

side note about `date` utility ::: the syntax is ***really*** different between `gnu/linux` one and `BSD` ones :

- `gnu` one allows for fractional epochs for input and output
- the `@` is a mandatory requirement for epochs

> ```
> gdate -d '@16602518201915245'    # GNU-date (GNU coreutils 9.1)
> ```

```
Mon Nov  8 22:07:25 EST 526114827
```

- BSD one won't accept `@` or non-integers

> ```
>  date -r 16602518201915245       # BSD-date (from FreeBSD 12.0)
> ```

```
Mon Nov  8 22:07:25 EST 526114827
```

they do share one common feature though :

- an upper-limit for the year **`-1 + 2 ^ ( 3 ^ 3 + 4 )`**